# When do we skip further conditions, when we have multiple conditions in a while loop?

Tags: c#, multiple-conditions

For example, when we have three conditions in a while loop:

```
while (true || false || false)
{
  //Do something...
}
```

**I am talking of conditions separated by the `||` operator only**. I believe when we encounter this while loop, as soon as the first `true` statement is encountered, we skip the other conditions.
I know this is true if we have two conditions in the while loop separated by the `||` operator. But, if we have more than two conditions, do we skip the further conditions, further down the while loop - when the first `true` condition is encountered?
This is because, the `while` loop does not know, how many more conditions we have in the `while` loop.  And would go further.
For two conditions, we would skip evaluating the conditions further, when the first `true` condition is encountered. But, when there are multiple conditions, separated by the `||` operator, would we still skip evaluating the other conditions, when the first `true` condition is encountered?
It would be helpful if you can tell me, what happens at Compile time and Run time, in this case (when we have multiple conditions in the `while` loop, separated by the `||` operator).
How do we know when to skip the further conditions?
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I doubt *the loop* cares much about the conditions at all.  The conditions here form an *expression*, and the loop only looks at the result of that expression.  That expression can be anything, as long as the result is a boolean value.  The rules for evaluating boolean expressions like this should be documented in the operators used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be helpful if you can tell me, what happens at Compile time and Run time, in this case (when we have multiple conditions in the while loop, separated by the || operator).

If you *literally* have `while(true || false || false)`, or equivalent compile-time constants that the compiler can deduce at compile time, then this will compile to the same code as `while(true)`, because `true || false || false` can be calculated at compile-time to be true. The compiler would also omit any code following the `while` loop, unless it could determine you're using a `break;` or some other construct that would allow the `while` loop to be exited.

Likewise, if you had something like `while(true && false)`, the entire `while` loop would be omitted from the compile-time code, because it would be deemed unreachable.

If you are using expressions with variables whose values cannot be determined at compile-time, such as `while(node == null || node.Value != value)`, then at run-time the first expression (`node == null`) will be evaluated, and if it's found to be `true` then the remainder of the expression will be *short-circuited* as specified by the docs that Guru Stron noted in his answer. (In the example I just gave, that would prevent `node.Value` from throwing a null reference exception.)

Comment: For what it's worth, if the compiler can figure out what you are doing (at compile time) and eliminates certain paths through your code, you will sometimes get unexpected "Unreachable code" warnings.

Comment: Did you mean to write `node != null`? As you have it right now you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that actual conditions are not constants (otherwise it does not make much sense, because they will be optimized by compiler to just `true`) - this is called "short-circuiting" and is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) for `&&` and `||` operators:

> #### Conditional logical AND operator &&
>
> The conditional logical AND operator `&&`, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical AND operator, computes the logical AND of its operands. The result of `x && y` is true if both `x` and `y` evaluate to `true`. Otherwise, the result is `false`. If `x` evaluates to `false`, `y` isn't evaluated.
>
> #### Conditional logical OR operator ||
>
> The conditional logical OR operator `||`, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical OR operator, computes the logical OR of its operands. The result of `x || y` is true if either `x` or `y` evaluates to `true`. Otherwise, the result is `false`. ***If `x` evaluates to `true`, `y` isn't evaluated***.

You can try using [`|` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-):

> #### Logical OR operator |
>
> The `|` operator computes the logical OR of its operands. The result of `x | y` is `true` if either `x` or `y` evaluates to `true`. Otherwise, the result is `false`.
> The `|` operator ***evaluates both operands even if the left-hand operand evaluates to `true`***, so that the operation result is `true` regardless of the value of the right-hand operand.

```cs
bool Get(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    return i == 1;
}

// prints 1 2 InWhile
while (Get(1) | Get(2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("InWhile");
    break;
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgsAKAAICYCMjECMD2OA2ABAOICmwAFAJZTCFUCUiA3ooe4UmgJzUMDcbDkgDs9QgF4JhNIIQBfTAgDuACyr5ShCmUpoGhGCXIUUDJglYIOnHhQBEASSgB1dZvsCh7LGFIBDAGs5eSA===)

Comment: So, if I have a `while` statement like `while(false || false || false || false || true || false)`, then all conditions will be evaluated until we reach true in the while loop, and all conditions after true will be skipped, right? - and we will enter the `while` loop.

Comment: @VikramSingh yes, all conditions until first `true` is encountered are evaluated.